# Harddisk Not Detected After Restart?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hardisk installed windows 7 ultimate. I installed  Ubuntu 12.04 by pen drive. After sometime it hanged. After waiting sometime, I press the key of reboot. After that one messege appeared "no boot device found". Then I went to my BIOS settings there I could not find my hardisk.

Comment: Are you able to unplug the drive from the motherboard and plug it back in? If the BIOS doesn't see it this might be a problem with your drive.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware problem. This one has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Make sure your hardware works; is the disk broken?

Comment: disk is not broken

Comment: How do you know this? An if not, then why doesn't your BIOS detect it?

Comment: after installation of ubuntu it is not shown on any computer

Comment: Software can break many things, but not the fact whether the disk is recognized by BIOS.